# Angular - SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime value

Tags: angular, laravel

I am developing an client portal application. Laravel-5.8 is the backend and Angular-7 is the frontend. I have this table:

table

```
CREATE TABLE `client_quotes` (
  `id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `address` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `business_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `truck_required` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `truck_type` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT 'Flatbed 20 Ton',
  `quote_origin` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `quote_destination` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `commodity` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `loading_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `comment` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

ApiController.php

```
    public function createClientQuote(Request $request) {
        $request->validate([
                    'first_name' => 'required',
                    'last_name' => 'required',
                    'email' => 'required|email',
                    //'email' => 'required|email|unique:users|max:255',
                    'phone' => 'required|max:14',
                    'business_name' => 'required',
                    'truck_type' => 'required',
                    'truck_required' => 'required',
                    'quote_origin' => 'required',
                    'quote_destination' => 'required',
                    'commodity' => 'required',  
                    // 'weight' => 'required',
                    'loading_date' => 'date|required' 
        ]);
        $clientquote = new ClientQuote;
        $clientquote->first_name=$request->get('first_name');
        $clientquote->last_name=$request->get('last_name');
        $clientquote->email=$request->get('email');
        $clientquote->phone=$request->get('phone');
        $clientquote->business_name=$request->get('business_name');
        $clientquote->truck_type=$request->get('truck_type');
        $clientquote->truck_required=$request->get('truck_required');
        $clientquote->quote_origin=$request->get('quote_origin');
        $clientquote->quote_destination=$request->get('quote_destination');
        $clientquote->commodity=$request->get('commodity');
        $loading_date=date_create($request->get('loading_date'));
        $format = date_format($loading_date,"Y-m-d H:i:s");
        $clientquote->loading_date = strtotime($format);
        $clientquote->save();

        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'Quote Successfully Sent!'
        ], 201);
    }
```

In the ApiController.php above, I tried to format the loading_date with these:

> ```
>     $loading_date=date_create($request->get('loading_date'));
>     $format = date_format($loading_date,"Y-m-d H:i:s");
>     $clientquote->loading_date = strtotime($format);
> ```

client-quote.component.html

```
    <form class="form-clientquote" #clientquoteForm=ngForm (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">

        <div class="col-xs-6">
        <label for="loading_date">Loading Date<span style="color:red;"> *</span></label>
        <div class="input-group date" style="width: 100%;" >
        <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput [matDatepicker] = "picker" placeholder = "Choose a date" name="loading_date" [ngModel]="form.loading_date | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy'" (ngModelChange)=" form.loading_date= $event"  #loading_date="ngModel" [ngClass]="{'is-invalid' : loading_date.invalid && ((loading_date.dirty || loading_date.touched) || clientquoteForm.submitted)}"   required>
          <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for] = "picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
           <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
           </mat-form-field>
           <div class="form-feedback" *ngIf="loading_date.invalid && ((loading_date.dirty || loading_date.touched) || clientquoteForm.submitted)">
              <div style="color:red;" *ngIf="loading_date.errors?.required"class="alert alert-danger">Loading Date is required.</div>
              </div>
           </div>
         </div>
     </div>
   </div>

   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-xs-12">
       <div class="col-xs-12">
       <div class="btn-group">
          <button style="margin:5px" (keyup.enter)="onSubmit()" type="submit" class="btn btn-success" awNextStep> Get A Quote</button>
       </div>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
   </form>
```

When I clicked on submit button, I expected the application to save into the database. I got this error:

> "SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime value: '1572307200' for column `clientportal`.`client_quotes`.`loading_date` at row 1 (SQL: insert into `client_quotes` (`first_name`, `last_name`, `email`, `phone`, `business_name`, `truck_type`, `truck_required`, `quote_origin`, `quote_destination`, `commodity`, `loading_date`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (Ademola, Adebila, decking@gmail.com, 09048614390, JOKA, I Don't know, 2, Ajegunle, Ebutt, Rice, 1572307200, 2019-10-02 11:15:42, 2019-10-02 11:15:42))"

I think the error has to do with the loading_date.  How do I resolve it?

Comment: Try to dump `$request->get('loading_date')` and `date_format($loading_date,"Y-m-d H:i:s")` and `strtotime($format)` to see the format of the date. It seems to be converted to timestamp somewhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a `datetime` column expects a value in `Y-m-d H:i:s` format. But you are trying to insert a UNIX timestamp like `1572307200`. So this is causing the problem. If you want a UNIX timestamp make the column type `varchar` or keep it as it is. You can convert it to UNIX timestamp later. So for now remove the `strtotime` function.

```
$loading_date=date_create($request->get('loading_date'));
$format = date_format($loading_date,"Y-m-d H:i:s");
$clientquote->loading_date = $format;
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the error code, it seems like the value of the loading_date property is a string representation of unix epoch, not a date-time-object.

As a fix, I'd advice you to migrate the SQL loading_date column to use string values and then convert the fe request value to ISO dateTimeString. Later, if you need to use methods native to dateTime- / Carbon -object, it's easy to parse the string from db as dateTime- / Carbon -object.

Additional benefit of this is that you can store time localization data too and you don't have to worry about future changes to libraries breaking your code.